# ajax call not successful even after variable is available

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In this code i m trying to populate dropdown list, when the variable `$place` is available. Made an ajax call to get the data from the listplace.php file which is encoded in json format

Problem is the dropdown list not populating from the php file done through ajax call. But when i `echo $_GET['place'];` it works and also the *listplace.php* also contains data but still not the dropdown populating. Please help!!

listplace.php output

```
{"option":["HBD T-Shirt"]}
```

Php Code

```
<?php
echo $_GET['place'];
?>

<select id="name">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
</select>


<?php if (isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] != '') { ?>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {place: '<?= $_GET['place'] ?>'},
            url: 'listplace.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.option.length) {
                    var $el = $("#name"); 
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                        $el.append($('<option>',
                            {
                                value: json.option[i],
                                text: json.option[i]
                            }));
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No data found!');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If the response is a JSON string then you may have to parse the response data like so `JSON.parse(json)`

Comment: Why are you using Ajax at all if you're already in a PHP page where the PHP `if` test is occurring? @SandeepNayak - jQuery will do that automatically given the `dataType: 'json'` setting.

Comment: @nnnnnn actually place variable is dynamic sometimes it will contain the data but sometimes it wont. thats y i tried to make ajax call using isset. But i couldnot understand why not its populating when every variable has got the data!

Comment: i tried output the response this way from listplace.php ** <?php
echo json_encode(array("option" => ["HBD T-Shirt"]));die;
?> **  it works for me.

Comment: yes @RanjeetSingh infact by mistake $place variable was not named properly but the code is perfect without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found out the solution due to a simple mistake, that instead of `$place` i mentioned as `$variable` now the ajax works perfectly.

There is a code `window.location = "1stlink.php?place=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);` here instead of $place i had put $variable so it dint work.